# When adding styles in Chrome's debugger, how can I accept an autocomplete suggestion?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

If I type

[image]

how can I accept the suggestion `perspective` and continue typing? I've tried `tab` and `enter`, both of which leave me with

[image]

I'd like it to leave me with

[image]

or better yet, with an opening parenthesis.

Using my mouse to select `perspective` from the dropdown works, but surely there's a faster way? ...while typing this question, I found that the right-arrow works also, but that's not in reach of home-row. Is there a faster key *that's in reach of home row*?

Answer (score 0):

Tabs works, but for the specific example, perspective is invalid value for transform property. You have to use perspective as below

```
  transform: perspective(600px);
```

So once you select perspective, don't tab out, go to the end of string an put your perspective value. You can use shift+ right arrow to move end of that string.